# Two VM Player guests block network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

Im having some trouble getting VM Player to run on

Host: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64.

I Have two guests

1. Win2012
2. Ubuntu 13.04.

It somehow jams the system and as it is a farm server i cant only assume it is the network communication. I checked the syslog and there are no error. So i have to reset it remotely. But after a couple of hours it keeps jamming. Iv tried with ubuntu 13.04 as host. Different versions of VMPlayer. Running one guest on VMPlayer and the other on VirtualBox. And a whole lot of other things, unsuccessfully.

Regards

Win Config

```
#!/usr/bin/vmware
.encoding = "UTF-8"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "9"
vcpu.hotadd = "TRUE"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsisas1068"
memsize = "8780"
mem.hotadd = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "win.vmdk"
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-raw"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "bridged"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000e"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "static"
usb.present = "FALSE"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
usb.vbluetooth.startConnected = "FALSE"
displayName = "win"
guestOS = "windows7srv-64"
nvram = "win.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
gui.exitOnCLIHLT = "FALSE"
powerType.powerOff = "hard"
powerType.powerOn = "hard"
powerType.suspend = "hard"
powerType.reset = "hard"
extendedConfigFile = "win.vmxf"
ide1:0.autodetect = "TRUE"
numvcpus = "4"
ethernet0.address = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
usb.generic.autoconnect = "FALSE"
vhv.enable = "FALSE"
uuid.location = "XX XX"
uuid.bios = "XX XX"
replay.supported = "FALSE"
replay.filename = ""
scsi0:0.redo = ""
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "160"
ide1:0.startConnected = "FALSE"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "192"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "-1"
vmci0.id = "777207447"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "35"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
cleanShutdown = "FALSE"
unity.wasCapable = "TRUE"
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
scsi0.sasWWID = "50 05 05 67 20 66 1c 80"
usb_xhci:1.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:3.present = "TRUE"
vm.genid = "425924755205015829"
vm.genidX = "-1671765623893518993"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "33554432"
softPowerOff = "FALSE"
usb_xhci:1.speed = "2"
usb_xhci:1.deviceType = "hub"
usb_xhci:1.port = "1"
usb_xhci:1.parent = "-1"
usb_xhci:3.speed = "4"
usb_xhci:3.deviceType = "hub"
usb_xhci:3.port = "3"
usb_xhci:3.parent = "-1"
hgfs.mapRootShare = "TRUE"
isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "FALSE"
sharedFolder.maxNum = "1"
sharedFolder0.present = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.enabled = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.readAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.writeAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.hostPath = "/tmp"
sharedFolder0.guestName = "tmp"
sharedFolder0.expiration = "never"
usb_xhci:4.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:4.deviceType = "hid"
usb_xhci:4.port = "0"
usb_xhci:4.parent = "1"
ehci.present = "FALSE"
usb_xhci.present = "FALSE"
sound.present = "FALSE"
serial0.present = "FALSE"
```

Ubuntu Config

```
#!/usr/bin/vmware
.encoding = "UTF-8"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "9"
numvcpus = "4"
vcpu.hotadd = "TRUE"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
memsize = "8024"
mem.hotadd = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "ubuntu.vmdk"
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-image"
floppy0.startConnected = "FALSE"
floppy0.fileName = ""
floppy0.autodetect = "TRUE"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "bridged"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000e"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "static"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ehci.present = "TRUE"
ehci.pciSlotNumber = "35"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.startConnected = "FALSE"
sound.fileName = "-1"
sound.autodetect = "TRUE"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
serial0.present = "TRUE"
serial0.fileType = "thinprint"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
usb.vbluetooth.startConnected = "FALSE"
displayName = "ubuntu"
guestOS = "ubuntu-64"
nvram = "ubuntu.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
gui.exitOnCLIHLT = "FALSE"
vhv.enable = "TRUE"
powerType.powerOff = "hard"
powerType.powerOn = "hard"
powerType.suspend = "hard"
powerType.reset = "hard"
extendedConfigFile = "ubuntu.vmxf"
ide1:0.autodetect = "TRUE"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "16"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "160"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "32"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "34"
vmci0.id = "274073946"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "36"
uuid.location = "56 4d 8a 07 35 aa 42 e8-85 22 99 4c 10 56 09 5a"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 8a 07 35 aa 42 e8-85 22 99 4c 10 56 09 5a"
cleanShutdown = "FALSE"
replay.supported = "FALSE"
replay.filename = ""
scsi0:0.redo = ""
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
usb:1.present = "TRUE"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "134217728"
softPowerOff = "FALSE"
usb:1.speed = "2"
usb:1.deviceType = "hub"
usb:1.port = "1"
usb:1.parent = "-1"
ethernet0.address = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
usb.generic.autoconnect = "FALSE"
serial0.startConnected = "FALSE"
ide1:0.startConnected = "FALSE"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
tools.remindInstall = "TRUE"
isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "FALSE"
sharedFolder0.present = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.enabled = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.readAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.writeAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.hostPath = "/tmp"
sharedFolder0.guestName = "tmp"
sharedFolder0.expiration = "never"
sharedFolder.maxNum = "1"
usb:0.present = "TRUE"
usb:0.deviceType = "hid"
usb:0.port = "0"
usb:0.parent = "-1"
```

Comment: What are the symptoms, and what have you tried?  There is nothing here that will help anyone help you.

Comment: The symptoms are. it blocks the machine (or the network connection). I thought maybe it smth about the configuration. should i chose different virtual network adapters? I dont have much experience with VMWare Player.

Comment: Define blocks in this case.

Comment: The system doesnt respond anymore. My guess is, its the network. I have to reset it anyways

Comment: i switched to virtualbox :|